# error while calling method in another class

Tags: java, xml, spring

i am new to Java. i have a method

```
 public class Lovefruits{


    public byte[] Eeee(String apple, String Banana, Map<String, byte[]> grapes, boolean orange){

        ///body///

       }
    }
```

when i call this method in another class as such

```
public class Allfruits{ 

private String apple;
private String banana;
private Map<String,byte[]> grapes;
private boolean orange;

 // constructor //


fruits = lovefruits.Eeee(String apple, String Banana, Map<String,byte[]> grapes, boolean orange);

}
```

its throws an error because of `Map<String,byte[]>`. 
i created all variables in the class i am calling this method. i dont know how to create this one `Map<String,byte[]>`

update when i do this

```
fruits = lovefruits.Eeee(apple, banana, grapes, orange);
```

it shows error The method `Eeee(apple, banana, grapes, orange)` from type lovefruits refers to missing type Map.

Comment: You haven't actually created the map for grapes. All you've done is declared that grapes is a Map<String, byte[]>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When **calling** a method you don't need to tell the compiler the types of the arguments. This

```
fruits = lovefruits.Eeee(String apple, String Banana, Map<String,byte[]> grapes, boolean orange);
```

should be

```
fruits = lovefruits.Eeee(apple, banana, grapes, orange);
```

You already gave the types with:

```
private String apple;
private String banana;
private Map<String,byte[]> grapes;
private boolean orange;
```

Comment: i did exactly like that. its throwing error The method lovefruits.Eeee(apple, banana, grapes, orange) from type lovefruits refers to the missing type Map.

Comment: `import java.util.Map;` - compile time errors are not usually described as "throwing", you need to fix all of the compilation errors before you can expect anything useful from running the code.

Comment: Oops i need to be watchful. That worked. Thanks Elliot.